# Zepto load function interupts hide show

Tags: ajax, mobile, zepto

We are building a mobile website with Zepto.js.  Most of our functionality is simple enough to avoid the bigger files needed with JQuery mobile. BUT ....

When I use .load() it seems to disrupt hide/show of related divs.  My page structure is:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="maincntr">
  Normal page
  content ...
  <div class="rvw">show more</div>
  </div>
  <div id="ajxcntr">

  </div>
</div>
```

The script is:

```
$('.rvw').click(function(){
$('#ajxcntr').show(),
$('#maincntr').hide(),
$('#ajxcntr').load('more/stuff.htm')
});

$('.bck').click(function(){
$('#maincntr').show(),
$('#ajxcntr').hide()
});
```

The stuff.htm contains a `<div class="bck">Back</div>`

The initial functions work fine, the divs are closed/opened and the file is loaded.  But the .bck hide/show functions don't work.  If I drop the .load() line from .rvw and simply trigger the show hide aspects everything works just fine for both.

So I am guessing there is an issue caused by the .load() aspect.  Any ideas or suggestions?

**after a break ...**

Got it sorted, I needed to initiate the .bck functions AFTER loading the extra content.

```
$('.rvw').click(function(){
   $('#ajxcntr').show(),
   $('#maincntr').hide(),
   $('#ajxcntr').load('reviews/th-north.htm', function(){  
       $('.bck').click(function(){
           $('#maincntr').show(),
           $('#ajxcntr').hide()
       })
   })
});
```